# YAxis Recharts почему не отображатеся значение у первой линии

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Почему у последней линии не отображается значение?

`

```
 <LineChart width={290} height={133} data={data}
                   margin={{ top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5 }}
        >
            <CartesianGrid stroke="#6E6E6E" opacity={.5}  vertical={false}/>
            <YAxis axisLine={false} width={14} tickCount={3} tickLine={false}  />
            <Line  type="monotone" dataKey="pv" stroke="#FE5000" dot={false} />
            <Line  type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#1993D0" dot={false} />
        </LineChart>[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
```

`

Comment: Покажите компонент <Line /> что бы можно было попробовать догадаться

Comment: Покажите что у вас лежит в data, так можно понять что проблема не в ключах dataKey